# How to generate thymeleaf template using spring and json

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to spring MVC and need to generate a form having questions of different type how can we generate thymeleaf template and pass this JSON in model

```
{
"docType": "assessmentForm",
"items": [
    {
        "id": "101",
        "docType": "question",
        "model": "text",
        "group": "A",
        "data": {
            "headingText": "Whats your name",
            "promptText": "whats your nick name",
            "responses": [
                {
                    "text": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "docType": "question",
        "model": "radio",
        "group": "B",
        "data": {
            "headingText": "Are you availabe at 5",
            "promptText": "Are you availabe at 5",
            "responses": [
                {
                    "text": "yes",
                    "value": "no"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "104",
        "docType": "question",
        "model": "choice",
        "group": "B",
        "data": {
            "headingText": "What all fruite you like",
            "promptText": "what all fruite you like",
            "responses": [
                {
                    "text": "Apple",
                    "value": "apple"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Banana",
                    "value": "banana"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Orange",
                    "value": "orange"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

This JSON needs to generate a form and submitted on the server with answers. can anybody help me in this

Comment: What do you want. Generate a template from JSON or fill a template with the JSON data?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli need to create a template like if a model is a radio so the question should have the radio buttons

Comment: _need to create a (Thymeleaf?) template_ It's a bit unclear to me from the information in the question why you would need to do this. It sounds like what you might need is a set of _predefined_ Thymeleaf fragments (one per model type), used in a _predefined_ Thymeleaf template with conditional logic controlling how it is all assembled. And a separate step up-front to deserialize the JSON data to Java beans.